# Google Cloud WordPress site displays site's ip address instead of the domain name. Cloudflare not redirecting traffic to site

Tags: wordpress, redirect, ip, cloudflare, ddos

I just moved a WordPress site to Google Cloud after the site experienced a DDos attack. I restored the site using UpdraftPlus backup files but I'm running into two issues: (1) The site redirects to the naked Google ipv4 domain instead of the registered domain name even though I set the A record for the ipv address to point to the site's domain name. I tried setting the site url in WordPress to the sites https domain name but it redirects to the hacker's site when I do that; (2) I'm trying to use CloudFlare to handle traffic on the site but Cloudflare is not directing traffic from some browsers to the site. When it does, it directs the traffic to the naked ipv4 address. I'm not sure why Cloudflare isn't working on some browsers. Not sure if it has anything to do with the time since I transferred the domain (<24 hours ago). On my pc Cloudflare works fine in Firefox, Opera, and Edge browsers but not in Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. I created a new Cloudflare account and set the URL in WordPress to the site's domain name. It appears the old Cloudflare account might have cached some information. Moving to a new account resolved the redirection issue.